# Adding all values with the same value in an adjacent column?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a customer order list which has a `date`, `customer ID`, and `amount purchased`.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Customer Order Worksheet]

I would like to consolidate all of these into a new sheet with the total amount each customer purchased. How would I achieve this?

I've considered going through each row and checking to see if its an existing customer or new one and adding it to an array. It does not seem like this would be efficient though.

Comment: Pivot Table is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple Excel functions.

[image]

`=SUMIFS(C$2:C3,$B$2:B3,B3)` copy this formula to the adjacent row of the first record, and drag it down. Take not of the locked starting cell of the array, and the dynamic ending cell of the array.

[image]

`=SUM((C3:C32)*(B3:B32=G5)*(A3:A32>=G3)*(A3:A32<=G4))` copy this formula and input it as an array formula. Hold Shift + Ctrl then press enter.

You can now change the Dates and CustId accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As per @ScottCraner's suggestion, a pivot table will provide the data in the format you want as per the code below.  If you don't have 'Sheet2', add it and run the code.  Source data is on "Sheet1" starting at row 3 as per the diagram in your question.  If you want to experiment I've included a macro to delete the pivot table.

```
Option Explicit


Sub CreatePivotTable()

  Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
  Dim pvt As PivotTable
  Dim strt As String, src As String

  With sht1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    src = .Name & "!" & Range("A3:C" & lastRow).Address
  End With
  strt = sht2.Name & "!" & sht2.Range("A1").Address

  'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                 SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=src)

  'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sht2.Range(strt), _
                                      TableName:="PivotTable1")
  'Add fields
  With pvt
    With .PivotFields("Customer ID")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Amount Purchased")
     .Orientation = xlDataField
     .Position = 1
    End With
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False
  End With
End Sub

Sub DeletePivotTable()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Clear
End Sub
```